# Selenium Webdriver times out on IE 11

Tags: c#, internet-explorer, selenium

I am having troubles running Selenium WEbdriver on IE 11 windows 7. The Send Keys are so slow. I have already downloaded the latest webdriver for IE but it won't still work. Below is the time out exception I kept receiving:

```
Test Name:  TestInInternetExplorer
Test FullName:  TravelTest_1.UnitTest1.TestInInternetExplorer
Test Source:    c:\Users\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\TravelTest_1\TravelTest_1\UnitTest1.cs : line 34
Test Outcome:   Failed
Test Duration:  0:01:36.7213961

Result Message: 
Test method TravelTest_1.UnitTest1.TestInInternetExplorer threw exception: 
System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException: The HTTP request to the remote WebDriver server for URL http://localhost:14927/session/41c432de-a158-4a14-bbc0-38a21cd67582/element/c9da6f89-09e9-4da9-a84a-ea262762491d/value timed out after 60 seconds. ---> System.Net.WebException: The operation has timed out
Result StackTrace:  
at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.HttpCommandExecutor.CreateResponse(WebRequest request)
 --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
    at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.HttpCommandExecutor.CreateResponse(WebRequest request)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.HttpCommandExecutor.Execute(Command commandToExecute)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.DriverServiceCommandExecutor.Execute(Command commandToExecute)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.Execute(String driverCommandToExecute, Dictionary`2 parameters)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebElement.SendKeys(String text)
 --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
    at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.UnsafeInvokeInternal(Object obj, Object[] parameters, Object[] arguments)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Support.PageObjects.WebDriverObjectProxy.InvokeMethod(IMethodCallMessage msg, Object representedValue)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Support.PageObjects.WebElementProxy.Invoke(IMessage msg)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.IWebElement.SendKeys(String text)
   at TravelTest_1.CreateTANonProxy_Domestic.FillGeneralInfo() in c:\Users\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\TravelTest_1\TravelTest_1\CreateTANonProxy_Domestic.cs:line 112
   at TravelTest_1.UnitTest1.CreateTADraft(IWebDriver driver) in c:\Users\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\TravelTest_1\TravelTest_1\UnitTest1.cs:line 123
   at TravelTest_1.UnitTest1.TestInInternetExplorer() in c:\Users\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\TravelTest_1\TravelTest_1\UnitTest1.cs:line 44
```

My code is below:

```
InternetExplorerOptions options = new InternetExplorerOptions();
options.IntroduceInstabilityByIgnoringProtectedModeSettings = true;

    using (IWebDriver IEDriver = new InternetExplorerDriver(options))
    {

        Console.WriteLine("Executed in IE 11");
        CreateTADraft(IEDriver);
        Console.WriteLine("Draft saved in IE 11");
    }
```

And below is the code that is having problems:

```
count = counter;
     if (count.Equals(counter))
     {
         count = count + 1;
         y = count;
     }
     try 
     {
         using (var context = new MainDataContext(Properties.Settings.Default.ConnectionString))
         {
             foreach (var e in context.TARequestForm.Where(x => x.Id == y))
             {
                 String contact = e.Phone;
                 String purpose = e.Purpose;
                 purposeBox.Clear();
                 purposeBox.SendKeys(purpose);
                 contactBox.Clear();
                 contactBox.SendKeys(contact);
             }
         }
     }catch(WebDriverTimeoutException e)
     {
         Console.WriteLine(e);
         throw e;
     }
```

I am not sure anymore of whatever workaround I can do. Btw, this actually runs in IE, it just stops in the middle of sending keys. Thanks.

Comment: at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse() timeout suggests that it has nothing to do with send key. Its likely the server did not respond in 60s

Comment: What does this mean @Steve? I have already increased my Implicitly waits because I thought this would resolve the problem apparently it didn't

Comment: it means its your webserver's problem. Or the connection is not properly setup. Or it could be the webserver did not properly setup for localhost. Without code/server log I cant say anything for sure

Comment: It could also be related to [this](https://github.com/seleniumhq/selenium-google-code-issue-archive/issues/5116). What version of Selenium are you using?

Comment: I have tried this same code again and it is working, for some reason I had to decrease the test string (eg, "test from database" is the sample string then I used "test"). I find it weird that it has to do that but I am thinking it is just a string test data anyway. What could be the issue here? My Selenium version is 2

Comment: You can bypass native SendKeys just by creating a method that uses a non-native JavascriptExecutor to set value of a field.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Added the following in code:

```
    InternetExplorerOptions options = new InternetExplorerOptions();
    options.IntroduceInstabilityByIgnoringProtectedModeSettings = true;
    options.RequireWindowFocus = true;
```

This sped up my sendkeys. The RequireWindowFocus resolved my issue. Thanks @Kolichikov